# How to find Multibit installation path?

Tags: software-installation

I am specifically looking for how to start multibit from the command line (it is a java program)

When you click on the unity search button and then launch an application from there, how do you find the location it is running from? i.e. I want to start an application from terminal but have no idea how to find the command to run it. (I have tried doing a sudo find / -name 'programName' but can't find it from there either)!

The program I am looking for I just realised was installed from a java executable so may be somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If no MultiBit shortcut is created, you can run MultiBit manually as follows:
>
> open a terminal window and 'cd' to your installation directory
> type `java -jar multibit-exe.jar`

You should have seen the following screen:

[image]

This is where multibit gets installed.

Try typing:

```
java -jar ~/MultiBit-0.5.16/multibit-exe.jar
```

and should work, unless you changed the installation path.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `whereis` command.
You just need to supply the name of the program, like this:
`whereis firefox`

To limit search results to binaries, use the `-b` option:
`whereis -b firefox`

Answer (score 1):

Commands related to an installed package are usually stored in `/usr/bin` directory.

For example,

```
ls /usr/bin | grep vlc
```

The above command displays the output as,

```
cvlc
nvlc
qvlc
rvlc
svlc
vlc
vlc-wrapper
```

So you can run the `vlc` command to start vlc application.